# Regular Expression for Email in Spring Roo

Tags: java, regex, email, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo and am having difficulty implementing the regular expression for the email field so that only properly formatted emails can be implemented into the field. When I run Tomcat and test the application using a local host I get a message saying

> Enter a valid email

and this message appears everytime a "." is entered or if there is a space anywhere.

The current regex I am using is:

```
"^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\\\+]+(\\\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Is it an issue with Spring Roo or am I just using the wrong regex?

Comment: You can use the Hibernate annotation @Email

Comment: I am using a MySQL database. Wouldn't that change anything?

Comment: @Email is an annotation you can put on your domain object.  It causes the validation framework to validate the item as a valid looking email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use regex written and debugged by somebody else.

Here are the examples:

[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/